# IDWriteGdiInterop::CreateBitmapRenderTarget failing

Tags: gdi, directwrite

I have an application which renders glyphs to a printer device context. Earlier, it used GDI and it worked fine.
But now, I'm trying to use Directwrite instead.

I've changed the existing ExtTextOut call and used IDWriteTextLayout::Draw function.

I need to pass an object implementing IDWriteTextRenderer interface in the draw function.

I've implemented the DrawGlyphRun callback in IDWriteTextRenderer interface using a call to IDWriteBitmapRenderTarget:: DrawGlyphRun. So, I need to create a IDWriteBitmapRenderTarget object.

I have the following code :

```
IDWriteFactory* pDWriteFactory = NULL;
IDWriteGdiInterop* pGdiInterop = NULL;
IDWriteTextLayout* pTextLayout = NULL;
IDWriteBitmapRenderTarget* pBitmapRenderTarget = NULL;
IDWriteRenderingParams* pRenderingParams = NULL;

hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
    __uuidof(IDWriteFactory), reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pDWriteFactory));

if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    pDWriteFactory = 0;
else
{
    hr = pDWriteFactory->GetGdiInterop(&pGdiInterop);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        pGdiInterop = 0;
}

hr = pGdiInterop->CreateBitmapRenderTarget((HDC)hDC, someWidth, someHeight, &pBitmapRenderTarget);
```

The device context hDC is being passed by a function in another dll.

Result: hr=E_FAIL

Maybe I'm missing out on something very basic, but I have little knowledge of device contexts and I'm new to DirectWrite. I need to know why the same HDC structure which is compatible with a ExtTextOut call is not being compatible with DirectWrite.

Also, since the HDC field is optional, if I pass NULL, it succeeds but nothing gets rendered by the draw function. What does passing NULL signify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure hDC is a valid memory device context, memory part is important. NULL argument means that target creates its own context compatible with screen/desktop. In any case nothing will be rendered automatically, you need to blit yourself from HDC returned by `GetMemoryDC` to your context, in other words target draws to this memory DC only, and what you do next is up to you.